How is van der Waals' constant b measure of repulsion
In van der Waals real gas equation, the constant 'b' determines the size of the molecules of gas ( excluded volume ), then I am not able to understand, how exactly it is a measure of repulsion?

Think about consequences of significant own volume of molecules. Elastic collisions, potential energy of collisions and increased pressure due increased wall collision rate. By expansion, part of potential energy is released and gas slightly warms up (But this effect is for most gases weaker that at attraction forces, having the opposite T effect). Air molecules reportedly spend in collisions about 0.7% of time.

Always do thorough search before asking, I am sure it must be explained on many sites, one great one is libretexts.org.

Thanks man, I always try searching first, I went through Atkins book and other sites as well but could not clearly understand

The constant $b$ is not really a measure of repulsion but from geometric considerations it is approximately four times the total volume of all $n$ molecules in the gas. The ideal gas equation can then be written as $p(V-b) = nRT$ and where $b$ reduces the total volume available and to keep $nRT$ the same the pressure has to increase at constant $T$. You can interpret this if you wish as the same number of molecules in a smaller container hence the pressure is greater as pressure arises only from molecule striking the walls of the container.

I have commented the repulsion aspect in context of his prior question about Joule-
Thomson and Boyle temperature, where molecules are during lasting collisions in a mutually repulsing state. That is not the case for ideal gas.

@Poutnik,   I don't quite follow, even in an ideal gas the molecule only repel, they just do so only at contact. I was not considering just an ideal gas in my answer as shown by the equation used.

It depends on ideal gas model interpretation. Some say molecules of an ideal gas do not even collide, as they have infinitesimal cross-section, that they collide just with a container. Significant own volume of real molecules leads to extra pressure that can be interpreted as effective repulsion, together with releasing collision energy at expansion. (H2, He ). // Let say ideal gas collisions are so rare they have no effects on both p increase and gas energy,

Increased pressure due increased wall collision frequency is due intermolecular collisions. Due this, frequency of wall collision for a molecule is higher than frequency given by free flight between the walls.

If real gas molecules magically did not collide (or not more than of ideal gas), and if there were no attraction forces, then the gas pressure would be the same as for ideal gas. Own volume of molecules alone, without increased collisions, would have no effect on the pressure.

@Poutnik I think we are saying the same thing but in different ways. Collisions are  proportional to  molecule radius $r$ as $r^2$  as a result of excluded volume thus increasing pressure as $r$ increases. (Assuming volume of molecules is small fraction of total volume) Alternatively the reduced volume term $(V-b)$ is also caused by volume exclusion due to a molecules finite size (with same restrictions $b/V\ll 1$) , and so gas has more collisions with walls simply because available volume is less.

I consider Bigger mols -> Less V  //  Bigger mols -> More mol cols -> More wall cols -> bigger pressure.   Less V NOT-> bigger pressure. // Verbosely there is no cause-effect connection Less V -> bigger p, but that they have the common cause.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
